# How to get all the user data from another table and include them on user list in laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder, eloquent-relationship

I am using 2 tables upon displaying my users in my users>index.blade

these 2

USER table

[image]

and COLLECTOR_MEMBERS table

[image]

The result is this

[image]

Now my problem is I want to connect to the other table called

COMMISSIONS table

[image]

to achieve this result

[image]

**MODELS**

COMMISSIONS Model

[image]

USER

[image]

COLLECTOR MEMBER

[image]

USER Controller index function

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $users = User::all();           
    $admins = User::whereHas('roles', function ($q) {
      $q->where('roles.name', '=', 'admin');
    })->get();

    $collectorList = User::whereHas('roles', function ($q) {
      $q->where('roles.name', '=', 'collector');
    })->with('collectorList')->get();

    $borrowers = User::whereHas('roles', function ($q) {
      $q->where('roles.name', '=', 'borrower');
    })->get();

    $userProfile = Auth::user()->id;

    if (Auth::User()->hasRole(['borrower','collector'])){
        return redirect('dashboard/profile/'.$userProfile);
    }

    return view('dashboard.users.index', compact('users','profile'))
            ->with('admins',$admins)
            ->with('borrowers',$borrowers)
            ->with('collectorList',$collectorList);
            // ->with('collectorBorrowers',$collectorBorrowers);
}
```

How wan I display the commission_amount column from commissions table? to make my list like this

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use sum aggregate function, your code should look like this.

```
$collectorList = User::whereHas('roles', function ($q) {
      $q->where('roles.name', '=', 'collector');
    })->with(['collectorCommission' => function($query) {
          $query->sum('commission_amount');
}])->get();
```

Assuming that you have this relationship in your user model

```
public function collectorCommission() [
   return $this->hasMany('App\Commissions', 'user_id');
}
```

> You cant use `belongsToMany` relationship since this relationship
>   requires you an intermediary table in your second argument.

You should use hasMany relationship considering that one user has many commissions.

Comment: Hi thank you @Qonvex620! I updated my question. The $collectorList is connected to another table it doesn't contain the commission_amount column.

Comment: what column do you want to sump up ?, commission amount is just an example, you can use any as long as that column exists in your other table

Comment: the column is from commissions table. i tried this,          $collectorList = User::whereHas('roles', function ($q) {
              $q->where('roles.name', '=', 'collector');
            })->with(['collectorCommission' => function($query) {
                  $query->sum('commission_amount');
        }])->get(); and I get 
Undefined variable: collectorCommission

Comment: you must have a collectorCommission  relationship in your user model before you use that.

Comment: I already Have the it on my user model. I also include that here in my question.

Comment: still the Undefined variable: collectorCommission.

Comment: Hi I reconstruct my whole question. That might have more sense than my original question.

Comment: The record is now showing if I do this "$collector->collectorCommission" it display the "[{"id":37,"payment_id":17,"user_id":17,"loan_id":30,"commission_amount":"2500.00","claimed":0,"paid":0,"abandonedLoanCharges":0,"created_at":"2020-02-03 00:00:00","updated_at":"2020-02-03 00:00:00"}] " but if i do this " {{$collector->collectorCommission->commission_amount}}"  it displays error "Property [commission_amount] does not exist on this collection instance."